# Как сложить элементы 2-ух массивов с разной длинной?

Tags: javascript

Нужно сложить значения двух массивов.

Сейчас есть такой код, но из-за разности длинны массивов, в консоли выводятся значения NaN, как исправить?

```js
var a = [5, 10, 25, 40];
var b = [10, 25, 40, 60, 70, 90, 100];

function calculate(a, b, c) {
  var a = [10, 15, 25, 30, 8];
  var b = prompt("Введите знак операции")
  var c = [25, 35, 40, 8, 4, 5, 8, 6];
  var z = [];
  if (Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(c)) {
    if (a.length >= c.length)
      length = a.length;
    else
      length = c.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      z.push(c[i] + a[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(z);
}
calculate()
```

Comment: одно интересно, почему когда вы вставляете код в вопрос, вы даже хотя бы чуть чуть его не форматируете, что всем было легче его читать?))

Comment: `(a.length >= c.length)` вот тут надо `<=`, так как вы сейчас берете длину большего массива, поэтому и получаете `NaN`, надо брать длину меньшего массива

Comment: @ThisMan в том то и дело, что в условии нужно взять массив с большей или равно длинной, по идее в массиве (z) должно быть столько же индексов сколько и у исходного найбольшего, только в цикле элемент с индексом [i] меньшего массива получается undefined, и при слаживании undefined и числа получается NaN

Comment: и что же должно быть в результирующем массиве на месте элементов, которых нет в меньшем? проверяйте на равность `undefined` и подставляйте что нужно, если совпало

Comment: @ThisMan Ну как вариант я думал заполнить их нулями, тогда и слаживание впринципе сработает, но на сколько это правильно я не знаю

Comment: _и что же должно быть в результирующем массиве на месте элементов, которых нет в меньшем_?

Comment: @ThisMan должны быть строки/числа с большего массива

Comment: просто на месте проверяйте, что элемент существует и если его нет, то подставляйте ноль

Comment: @ThisMan         for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if(a[i]==undefined)
            a[i]=0;
            
            else if (c[i]==undefined)
            c[i]=0;
            


        
         z.push (c[i]+a[i]);

Comment: @ThisMan как-то так?

Comment: примерно, но лучше не изменять начальный массив, имхо. А просто сохранить в отдельные переменные и использовать их

Comment: @ThisMan Ок, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function calculate(a, b, c) {
  const firstArr = [10, 15, 25, 30, 8];
  const secondArr = [25, 35, 40, 8, 4, 5, 8, 6];
  const result = [];
  let length;
  
  if (firstArr.length >= secondArr.length) {
    length = firstArr.length;
  } else {
    length = secondArr.length;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // Проверяем что элементы есть, либо заменяем их нулями.
    const a = firstArr[i] === undefined ? 0 : firstArr[i];
    const b = secondArr[i] === undefined ? 0 : secondArr[i];
    result.push(a + b);
  }
  console.log(result);
}
calculate()
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручили)